# Making a website/project Portable

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-ajax, portability, custom-server-controls, portable-database

Good evening/morning/after/noon.

I have an ASP.net 3.5 website and I am using vb.net in VWD 2008 Express, I am also using MS SQL Server 2008 Express, I used ajax tabs and a textBox charavters counter control develped by https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/
The database is attached with MS SQL Server Management Studio Express and the files are stored in the SQL default "Data" folder.

The whole project's code and forms are stored in a folder in my E drive.
I need to hand the whole project to another coworker who have to finish it, please describe in steps how can i make my website portable (like i can put it all in a folder that he can carry around in his flash disk).

**PS**: I have had a problem trying to move the project from one server to the other, the pproject seems to look for the dlls of the AJAX control and the textBox counter where i originally unzipped the folders in which they cam in, which i think was on my desktop, although when i added those controls to the Tools tab, i created a new tab, then i choose the dll from the where i unzipped the controls source code, aint that enough?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the structure, make a folder for referenced files in the source tree. You can then reference from there. If you do that the entire tree is portable. The only changes, from environ, to environ, are configuration elements. And, if on the local system, you use SQL Express and put in the App_Data folder, it cana connect to your coworkers system, as long as he also has SQL Express.